# Forward declaring a function with defined array size in Objective-C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm sure that this is quite a silly question, but it's really caught me off guard and it may be that I'm just not thinking this through correctly. I've ran into the following line of code when working with OpenGL ES 2.0

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Forward declarations
static void SceneMeshInitIndices(
   GLushort meshIndices[NUM_MESH_INDICES]);
static void SceneMeshUpdateNormals(
   SceneMeshVertex mesh[NUM_MESH_COLUMNS][NUM_MESH_ROWS]);
static void SceneMeshUpdateMeshWithDefaultPositions(
   SceneMeshVertex mesh[NUM_MESH_COLUMNS][NUM_MESH_ROWS]);
```

Now, what catches me off guard is the fact that the functions declare their input as a 2D array with a specific size. I've never seen this done like this and am completely unsure of if it's legal or how it's legal within Objective-C. I've always been told to use a pointer to the original array and pass that it in. But this, just seems odd. Could anyone try explaining this to me or point out what I'm deducting wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When passing arrays to functions, they decay into pointers according to a set of rules. These are:

One. The first level of indirection (i. e. the first dimension/index of an array) decays into a pointer, thus its size need not be specified (nor is it used).

Two. Further dimensions of the array remain unchanged, and don't decay into a pointer. They need to be specified, and they are part of the type of the argument.

That's why essentially the following are equivalent and legal:

```
void foo(int arr[]);
void foo(int arr[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE]);
void foo(int *arr);
```

But the following are **not equivalent,** yet legal:

```
void foo(int arr[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]);
void foo(int **arr);
```

The following are again equivalent and legal:

```
void foo(int arr[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]);
void foo(int arr[][MAX_COLUMNS]);
```

(and these are interpreted as `int (*arr)[MAX_COLUMNS])`, i. e. as a pointer-to-array).

And the following is **illegal,** i. e. it generates a compiler error:

```
void foo(int arr[MAX_ROWS][]);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't void foo(int arr[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]); and
void foo(int arr[][MAX_COLUMNS]); not be considered equal as the second declaration can have say void foo(int arr[MAX_ROWS + 1][MAX_COLUMNS]) as a parameter while the second declaration can't?

Comment: I haven't ever thought of a needing to pass a multi-dimensional array as an argument... awesome, seems more standard C to pass in a pointer and vars containing the dimensions to figure out the offset, but +1

Comment: @TheGamingArt If I write "the first dimension doesn't matter", then I mean that the first dimension doesn't matter.

Comment: Odd, I reread your posting and didn't mean to offend you. I was honestly curious. Seems a little bizarre to specify something that doesn't matter to me XD

Comment: @TheGamingArt It is bizarre; C's entire treatment of arrays is bizarre.

Comment: @TheGamingArt No, you were not offensive. I just didn't understand your problem (I believed I explained it well enough, but apparently you had questions even after that :)

Answer (score 1):

> I've always been told to use a pointer to the original array and pass that it in.

You've been told to use a pointer to *an element of* the original array. You've been told this because if you try to declare a function that takes an array by value the language specifies that the parameter type is 'adjusted' to take a pointer to the element type (effectively causing the array parameter type to forget its size and to be passed by reference instead of by value). So basically you've been told to do the adjustment manually so that the source code accurately and explicitly represents the actual truth.

The declarations you show could also be declared using this advice:

```
static void SceneMeshInitIndices(GLushort *meshIndices);
static void SceneMeshUpdateNormals(SceneMeshVertex (*mesh)[NUM_MESH_ROWS]);
static void SceneMeshUpdateMeshWithDefaultPositions(SceneMeshVertex (*mesh)[NUM_MESH_ROWS]);
```

It should be clear that a type of `int [X][Y]` means 'an array of X arrays of Y ints.' So the element type is 'an array of Y ints.' So the adjusted type is 'int (*)[Y]' or 'a pointer to an array of Y ints.'

---

The rule that 'adjusts' the parameter types is one of the several reasons raw arrays are awful and should not be used if it's possible to avoid them. Unfortunately C doesn't really have a good way to do that, but C++ has `std::array`, which behaves as arrays ought to; i.e. you can pass them by value, you can return them by value, they don't ever automatically convert to a pointer to the element type (so they never forget their size), etc.

---

Maybe more examples will make it clearer. If you wrote:

```
void foo(int param[10]);
```

And you weren't aware of the rule that adjusts the parameter type then you might expect the following code to produce an error:

```
int bar[5];
foo(bar); // error? an array of 5 ints is not the expected type.
```

And for this code:

```
int baz[10];
foo(baz);
```

You might expect the array `bar` to be copied into the parameter, and that any modifications done on the parameter would have no effect on the original array. Unfortunately these entirely reasonable expectations are wrong. When you write `void foo(int param[10]);` the compiler sees the parameter with the array type and modifies it to be the same as if you'd written `void foo(int *param);`

Thus when you write `foo(bar)` the compiler sees that the function takes an `int*` (not the `int[10]` that you wrote), sees that it can convert `bar` to an `int *` and so instead of reporting an error the compiler maliciously produces a program which calls the function. No matter that the type you wrote is incompatible with the variable passed, no matter that the body of `foo()` could do something like `param[9] *= 2;` and ought to be assured that this is well defined.

Similarly, `foo(baz)` does not pass the array by value and anything done to the array parameter inside the function is done directly on the actual array. This is utterly unlike the usual C semantics where everything is passed by value/copy and the only way to 'pass by reference' is to obtain a pointer value that acts as a reference to another object. In this case the compiler automatically obtains a pointer on your behalf and effectively passes the array by reference.

Additionally, note that whether you write `void foo(int [10])` or `void foo(int [100])` doesn't matter; in both cases the parameter type is adjusted to `int *` and therefore those declarations declare the same function, even though they appear to be different.

Comment: I'm still a little vague on the adjustments you're reference (and I'm not remotely new to arrays at all). And for corrections of the terminology above I did mean I've been taught to reference the memory address of the original array to avoid the redundancy in copying the array data back and forth. Thank you guys for the great answers though. I actually think I do vaguely remember something like this when I dealt with C++ and the rule of thumb for defining sizes in the order last to first within function calls.

Comment: @TheGamingArt The rules for raw arrays in C and C++ are identical so you shouldn't notice a difference.

Comment: I think I completely understand what you're saying now. I was overthinking what you were saying earlier and pretty much take it for granted that when typing in the array name (say bar) it's instantly a pointer reference to the original rather a copy. Thank you again for taking out the time to describe that :). I think in essence when you explain it like this, it just adds iron to what was said earlier in the fact that the first piece of a dimensional array means nothing in a function parameter declaration because it's taken as a memory reference. Now that I think about this, that's very odd.

Comment: So what is the point in the call noted above them? I mean... what's the point in specifying the parameters if it's honestly meaningless (except for the 2nd dimension of the array). Is it just for semantics? Tidiness?

Comment: @TheGamingArt it's basically just documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To verify ontop of what's been noted above, I have also found the following explanation (that basically states I haven't needed to pass a 2D array in quite some time) that just iterates what's above.

When declaring a single-dimensional array as a formal parameter inside a function, you learned that the actual dimension of the array is not needed; simply use a pair of empty brackets to inform the C compiler that the parameter is, in fact, an array.This does not totally apply in the case of multidimensional arrays. For a two-dimensional array, the number of rows in the array can be omitted, but the declaration must contain the number of columns in the array. So the declarations

```
int array_values[100][50]
```

and
    int array_values[][50]

are both valid declarations for a formal parameter array called array_values containing
100 rows by 50 columns; but the declarations

```
   int array_values[100][]
```

and

```
int array_values[][]
```

are not because the number of columns in the array must be specified.